# How to find out system is entering the Modern Standby mode in Windows service using C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I’m working on a Windows service which is written in C#. I needed to find out if the system is entering the sleep mode and if it is resuming from sleep mode to execute some processes and set some variables. I used System Management to do that, but it does not get the Modern Standby entering event callback.

My service works fine on devices which does not support Modern Standby, but no event is raised on the devices that support this standby mode.
Is there a way to get this event?

Here is part of the code that takes care of the power management monitoring:

```
         WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("Win32_PowerManagementEvent");
         _powerManagementWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
         _powerManagementWatcher.EventArrived += PowerEventArrived;
         _powerManagementWatcher.Start();

.
.
.
.
        private void PowerEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int eventType = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value);
            Log.Info($"System power event called. Event type number: {eventType}");

            if (eventType == 7) // PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND 
            {
                Log.Info("System is waking from sleep.");
            }
            else if (eventType == 8) // PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY
            {
                Log.Info("System is resuming from standby.");
            }
            else if (eventType == 4) // PBT_APMSUSPEND
            {
                Log.Info("System is going to sleep.");

            }
            else if (eventType == 5) // PBT_APMSTANDBY 
            {
                Log.Info("System is going to Standby mode.");
            }
        }
```